# Execute an onclick function alone in every tr when $(this) clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to execute the same code in every items in tr when it's clicked. The items are the same in all tr elements. So the problem is, the script didn't found any miss-much and execute the first element found with this id

Here is the HTML code when I need it:

```
<tbody id="bList">
<tr class="">
    <td class="center" style="display:none;"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="center"></td>
    <td class="center"></td>
    <td class="center" style="width:200px !important;">
        <span id="timer" class="countdown callback ended" onclick="return false;"
              data-inc="0" data-time="10" data-id="btc2" rel="nofollow"></span>
        <span id="starter" class="" active="yes"> > </span>
    </td>
    <td class="center">
        <span id="open" class="">Open</span>
    </td>
    <td class="center"></td>
    <td class="center"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="selected">
    <td class="center" style="display:none;"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="center"></td>
    <td class="center"></td>
    <td class="center" style="width:200px !important;">
        <span id="timer" class="countdown callback ended" onclick="return false;"
             data-inc="0" data-time="10" data-id="btc1" rel="nofollow"></span>
            <span id="starter" class="" active="no"> > </span>
        </td>
        <td class="center">
            <span id="open" class=""> Open </span>
        </td>
        <td class="center"></td>
        <td class="center"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

To add selected class to the tr when clicked, I'm using .siblings() function with jquery. But I tried with it to execute the same wanted action, but I didn't figure it out.

this is the scripts that I tried:

```
$('#open').click(function(){
    /*$(this).parent().parent().find('td:nth-child(5) #starter')
             .html('Start Timer!&nbsp;>');*/
    if($(this).parent().parent().find('#timer').hasClass('ended'))
    {
        $(this).parent().parent().find('#starter').html('Start Timer!&nbsp;&nbsp;>')
               .attr({'active':'yes'});
    }else{
         //You can ignore this part. It does display a modal.
        if($('#starterModal').is(':hidden')){
            $('#starterModal').show().wait(6000).hide();
        }
    }
});

$('#starter').click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('active') == "yes"){
        $(this).parent().find('#timer').click();
        $(this).html('>').attr({'active':'no'});

        //Update rewards taken
        console.log($(this).parent().parent().find('td:nth-child(1)').html());
        $.ajax({
            //You can ignore it either. It's working fine.
            type : 'POST',
            url  : '../files/php/update_rewardHistory.php',
            data : {id : $(this).parent().parent().find('td:nth-child(1)').html(), 
                    currency : "btc"
                   },
            success : function(data){}
        });
    }else{
        //You can ignore this part! It does display a modal.
        if($('#starterModal').is(':hidden')){
            $('#starterModal').show().wait(6000).hide();
        }
    }
});

$('#bList tr').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    //console.log($(this).parent().parent().find('td:nth-child(1)').html());
});
```

So, is there a way to doing that?

Comment: An `id` should be unique! Use `class` instead.

Comment: yes i know that id should be unique! and i want to make it looks unique only in <tr> element. even with classes, i think it will be the same problem.

Comment: Please read this [mcve] - specifically the 'minimal' part - most of your code is marked "you can ignore this part" - if we can ignore it, then it shouldn't be in the question.  It's too confusing as to what the actual issue is.  You can use something like jsfiddle to recreate the issue.

Comment: i'm sorry about that, i will create it in jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments an `id` should be unique.
So to make this work, swap to classes and it will work fine:

```js
$('.open').click(function() {
  var tr = $(this).closest('tr') ,
      timer = tr.find('.timer') ,
      starter = tr.find('.starter');
  
  if( timer.hasClass('ended')) {
    starter.html('Start Timer!&nbsp;&nbsp;>').attr({
      'active': 'yes'
    });
  } else {
    if ($('#starterModal').is(':hidden')) {
      $('#starterModal').show().wait(6000).hide();
    }

  }
});

$('.starter').click(function() {
  var elem = $(this),
      tr = elem.closest('tr'),
      timer = tr.find('.timer');
  if(elem.attr('active') == "yes") {
    timer.click();
    elem.html('>').attr({
      'active': 'no'
    });

    //update rewards taken
    console.log(tr.find('td:nth-child(1)').html());
    /*$.ajax({ //you can ignore it also! it's working fine!

      type: 'POST',
      url: '../files/php/update_rewardHistory.php',
      data: {
        id: $(this).parent().parent().find('td:nth-child(1)').html(),
        currency: "btc"
      },
      success: function(data) {}
    });*/

  } else { //you can ignore this part! do display a modal
    if ($('#starterModal').is(':hidden')) {
      $('#starterModal').show().wait(6000).hide();
    }
  }
});

$('#bList tr').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
  //console.log($(this).parent().parent().find('td:nth-child(1)').html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="">
      <td class="center" style="display:none;"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="center"></td>
      <td class="center"></td>
      <td class="center" style="width:200px !important;">
        <span class="timer countdown callback ended" onclick="return false;" data-inc="0" data-time="10" data-id="btc2" rel="nofollow"></span>
        <span class="starter" active="yes"> > </span>
      </td>
      <td class="center">
        <span class="open">Open</span>
      </td>
      <td class="center"></td>
      <td class="center"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="selected">
      <td class="center" style="display:none;"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="center"></td>
      <td class="center"></td>
      <td class="center" style="width:200px !important;">
        <span class="timer countdown callback ended" onclick="return false;" data-inc="0" data-time="10" data-id="btc1" rel="nofollow"></span>
        <span class="starter" active="no"> > </span>
      </td>
      <td class="center">
        <span class="open"> Open </span>
      </td>
      <td class="center"></td>
      <td class="center"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Think you @Pilatus was suggested the same solution and it's working fine for me!

Answer (score 2):

At first you should know that an `ID` should be unique. When handling `Click` events on multiple `elements` use `class` instead.

It will always fire on the first element since `jQuery` expects that the `ID` is unique.

```
$('.starter').click(function(){ 
    //code
})
```

Comment: it's working perfectly as i want it! :) thank you! Your answer will be confirmed  to share it.